# iOS - UITableView in UIScrollView - Swipe to show another contents

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, swipe

I'm developing chat application. Which has some requirements like show message sent / receive time when user swipe on table view.

**Reference app :**

- Skype
- iMessage
- Public

I've attached on screen shot to help easily understand my requirement.

[image]

**If any library available. Please send a link. Thanks**

Comment: Do you have chats in table view?

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for external solution, rather than developing yourself check this library, it's very simple to use and it has the required capabilities.

https://github.com/SocialObjects-Software/SOMessaging

Or if you want to do it from scratch check this tutorial :

http://www.appcoda.com/socket-io-chat-app/

Comment: Thanks vasilev. Great tutorial. But i have many dependancy for my tableview and cell also. So i cant't inherit inbuilt classes. I need some quick code that make it easy. Thanks again